# Better solution for looping from filter and findIndex? Shorter solution ? JS

Tags: javascript

I need to find better or shorter solution for this looping.

```js
let filteredTraining = this.trainingPlan.trainingTemplateExercises.filter(
  (al) => al == trainingExerciseId
);
let index = this.trainingPlan.trainingTemplateExercises.findIndex(
  (el) => el == filteredTraining[0]
);
this.trainingPlan.trainingTemplateExercises.splice(index, 1);
```

This is just part of the function code but I think it can be written much better. It doesn't matter what the values ​​of the variables are.

Answer (score 1):

If the current code works, and the element is always found, then you just need an `indexOf`:

```
const { trainingTemplateExercises } = this.trainingPlan;
trainingTemplateExercises.splice(trainingTemplateExercises.indexOf(trainingExerciseId) , 1);
```

If the element might not exist, you'll need to check that the index isn't -1 before splicing:

```
const { trainingTemplateExercises } = this.trainingPlan;
const index = trainingTemplateExercises.indexOf(trainingExerciseId);
if (index !== -1) {
  trainingTemplateExercises.splice(index , 1);
}
```

If the array doesn't contain duplicate elements, and you can reassign the array instead of mutating it, I'd prefer that over `splice`:

```
this.trainingPlan.trainingTemplateExercises = this.trainingPlan.trainingTemplateExercises
  .filter(el => el !== trainingExerciseId);
```